# Php on IIS 10 windows10x64

Tags: php, iis

все источники показывают как развернуть php сайт на примере простого вывода информации о php. в моем сайте на php код работает не весь вот пример:
код останавливается на `socket_create(...);` он просто игнорируется и ничего соответственно не сообщает... Кто сталкивался с таким? может кто знает почему так? (устанавливал php через web установщик от microsoft, тестовый сайт работает)

Comment: Какой файл для запуска php Вы указали в IIS? `php.exe`?

Comment: @Eugene Master, расскажите более подробнее, что вы делаете.

Comment: `<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;');
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(); 
$address = '192.168.2.18'; 
$port = 5800;
if (($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) < 0)
{
     echo "Ошибка создания сокета";
}
else {
     echo "Сокет создан\n";
     }`

Comment: Вам необходимо добавить отображение ошибок на странице: https://karashchuk.com/PHP/error_reporting-display_errors-display_startup_errors/